# What is the max amount of rupees?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In BotW, they did away with the wallet sizes. You can always take in more and more rupees.

But at some point, can you max the number of rupees you can get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the image [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/6137ds/hitting_the_rupee_cap_in_breath_of_the_wild/), it appears that the rupee cap in Breath of the Wild is **999,999**. The person who discovered this did so through hacking, as it would take an extremely long time to get this much moolah.

For reference, here is the image in the thread:

> [image: 999,999]